# Regular expression in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to use REGEXP_LIKE in my table to check if the score of the game has the pattern:

(1 or 2 numbers)x(1 or 2 numbers)

My attempt was to use this expression

```
CONSTRAINT CK_PLACAR CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PLACAR, '^[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+$', 'i'))
```

But I'm not able to insert a score like '1x0'. I also tried some other options, like:

```
CONSTRAINT CK_PLACAR CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PLACAR, '^[[:digit:]]{1,2}x[[:digit:]]{1,2}$', 'i'));
CONSTRAINT CK_PLACAR CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PLACAR, '^[[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]x[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*$', 'i'));
```

I tried to change [[:digit:]] to [0-9] as well, but it didn't work either.

Here is my complete table:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTIDA (
TIME1 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
TIME2 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
DATA DATE NOT NULL,
PLACAR CHAR(5) DEFAULT '0x0',
LOCAL VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PARTIDA PRIMARY KEY (TIME1, TIME2, DATA),
CONSTRAINT FK_PARTIDA FOREIGN KEY (TIME1, TIME2) REFERENCES JOGA(TIME1, TIME2),
CONSTRAINT CK_PLACAR CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PLACAR, '^[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+$', 'i'))
);
```

Here is my test case:

```
INSERT INTO PARTIDA VALUES ('TIME1', 'TIME2', SYSDATE, '1x0', 'ESTADIO1');
```

Here is the output:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   INSERT INTO PARTIDA VALUES ('TIME1', 'TIME2', SYSDATE, '1x0', 'ESTADIO1')
>   Error report -
>   ORA-02290: check constraint (K9012931.CK_PLACAR) violated

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: The plus sign after the digit means 1 or more but you only allocated size for 2 on each side of the 'x'.  Either increase the size of the column or restrict what the regex allows.

Comment: Adding this comment here also so you see it.  Make column PLACAR a VARCHAR2 instead of a CHAR and it should work. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @Gary_W It's because CHAR are fixed-width - if you don't use the whole 5 bytes in this case, your data gets right-padded with spaces, which makes it fail the regexp.

Comment: Is 1*234 is valid data or constraint should fail ?

Comment: @kfinity  Thanks for the info.  If I make the regex `'^\d{1,2}x\d{1,2} *$'` to allow for the padding of 0 or more spaces like you said it works. Good to know but I'd stick with using VARCHAR2 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'^\d{1,2}x\d{1,2}$'` for at least 1 but not more than 2 digits on either side of the 'x'.

Maybe it's the syntax?  Try this:

```
  ALTER TABLE score_table ADD (
    CONSTRAINT CK_PLACAR
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PLACAR, '^\d{1,2}x\d{1,2}$', 'i'))
    ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

EDIT thanks to kfinity's comment above.  With PLACAR having a datatype of CHAR(5), that's a fixed-width datatype so if the data entered is less than 5 characters it gets padded with spaces causing it to not match the regex pattern.  Either change the datatype to VARCHAR2(5) which is variable width and preferred, or change the regex to allow for possible zero or more spaces at the end:

```
'^\d{1,2}x\d{1,2} *$'
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I edited my question, adding the complete table and the test case.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Gary W's answer, you can also modify it to not accept scores like '0x' (01, 02, 03, ...) but accept 0 or simply 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
^(?!0\d)\d{1,2}x(?!0\d)\d{1,2}$
```

Comment: Sorry I edited your answer instead of my own!  duh  P.S. Oracle does not support negative lookaheads though.